# javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on event:'prePersist'

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, bean-validation

Given two entities `Department` and `Employee` forming a unidirectional one-to-many relationship from `Department` to `Employee` based on respective tables in the database in question as follows.

```
public class Department implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "department_id", nullable = false)
    private Long departmentId;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "department_name", length = 255)
    private String departmentName;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(length = 255)
    private String location;

    @Version
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "row_version", nullable = false)
    private Long rowVersion;

    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName = "department_id", nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>(0);

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Constructors + getters + setters + hashcode() + equals() + toString().
}
```

```
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)

    private Long employeeId;
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(name = "employee_name", length = 255)
    private String employeeName;

    @Version
    @Basic(optional = false)        
    @Column(name = "row_version", nullable = false)
    private long rowVersion;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Constructors + getters + setters + hashcode() + equals() + toString().
}
```

While persisting this relationship as follows,

```
Department department = new Department();
department.setDepartmentName("x");
department.setLocation("x");

Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setEmployeeName("x");
department.getEmployeeList().add(employee);
entityManager.persist(department);
```

the following exception is caused.

```
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton SingletonEntry
javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton SingletonEntry
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:476)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$000(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:74)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:647)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:158)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:166)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy421.persistUnidirectional(Unknown Source)
    at ejb.__EJB31_Generated__EmployeeSessionBean__Intf____Bean__.persistUnidirectional(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:414)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at ejb.EmployeeSessionBean$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.persistUnidirectional(Unknown Source)
    at ejb.SingletonEntry.test(SingletonEntry.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1035)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor220.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:205)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor234.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:986)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:72)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:412)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:375)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:2014)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:468)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.validateOnCallbackEvent(BeanValidationListener.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.BeanValidationListener.prePersist(BeanValidationListener.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyListener(DescriptorEventManager.java:748)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.notifyEJB30Listeners(DescriptorEventManager.java:691)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.DescriptorEventManager.executeEvent(DescriptorEventManager.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectClone(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4314)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4291)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4233)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at ejb.EmployeeSessionBean.persistUnidirectional(EmployeeSessionBean.java:238)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor220.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 89 more
```

The culprit is the `@NotNull` constraint in the `Department` entity enforced on the field `rowVersion` marked by `@Version`. If this annotation is removed, then it goes fine - the persist operation succeeds in its entirely.

What role is played by the `@NotNull` constraint in this case?

<sub>The unidirectional relationship is not relevant. The exact same thing happens even though the relationship is changed to bidirectional one-to-many from `Department` to `Employee.`</sub>

Comment: Look at the default value definition.

Comment: `columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20) default '0'"` has no effect. Besides, it is a proprietary attribute (database-dependent) merely used to generate a column definition for the associated column in the underlying database table while generating the corresponding DDL statement, when the table generation strategy is used. I do not think, it sets a default value to a property in an entity. "*The SQL fragment that is used when generating the DDL for the column. Defaults to the generated SQL to create a column of the inferred type. `Default : ""`.*"

Comment: That's the point, the entity doesn't need to have a default value, but a database can have it, especially if not null constraint is enabled on the table. It means if you don't have to initialize it manually, which is looks ugly. Doing that you deprive the entity being validated, since the property doesn't require it anymore.

Comment: There is an awesome validation logic over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26817611/1851289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the version isn't actually set until the entity is modified, therefore `rowVersion` is `null` when the entity is first created. That fails your "not null" check. Try this instead and see if it works:

```
@Version
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "row_version", nullable = false)
private Long rowVersion = 0L;
```

What JPA implementation are using?

Comment: The JPA implementation is EclipseLink 2.6.0.

Comment: @Tiny: Glad that helped. It wouldn't surprise me if Hibernate or some other implementation worked anyway. In my experience anything not explicitly defined by JPA leads to behavior that's anybody's guess.