# How to make EclipseLink automatically print violated constraints if ConstraintViolationException occurs

Tags: spring, logging, eclipselink, spring-data-jpa, bean-validation

I have Spring backend with few modules with few tens of controllers and services. When somewhere in this services occurs ConstraintViolationException in log file I see only common exception, and there is not specified which exactly constraints are violated:

```
javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callbackevent:'preUpdate'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.
```

In JPA Specification and Bean Validation API there is no appointments about printing out violations. If I don't mistake in Hibernate all violated constraints are printed out automatically.

1. Is there any mechanism to say eclipselink to print violated constraints or maybe any mechanism to define system-wide custom printer of violations?
2. If no, do I have to manually implement printing of violated exceptions in each controller and service? Or maybe some mechanism like `@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler` is exist? (`@ExceptionHandler` is not convenient for internal services)

Comment: Yes, Hibernate will output the violations in the exception message by default. No idea why EclipseLink doesn't do that.

Comment: Created https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519573

Comment: The validation logic for your case is provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26817611/1851289

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, EclipseLink cannot be configured to output the errors.

With Spring Data JPA you can specify the repository base class:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = MyRepositoryImpl.class)
```

Override `save()` in the base class to handle the exception and output detailed information.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories