# javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted

Tags: jpa, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-7

I'm a student :D and I'm working on a project for Web Technologies. I have to work in JavaEE in JSF framework with JPA, EJB, JDBC, and I have a problem.

```
        Warning:   #{cc.attrs.loginButtonAction}: javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
javax.faces.FacesException: #{cc.attrs.loginButtonAction}: javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at
```

All errors
https://shrib.com/#Gaur8rM4LwV

And my code.

EJB. Controller with database

```
@Stateless
public class UsersFacade extends AbstractFacade<Users> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "OtoNaszDomPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }
//...
//...
    public String LoginAuthentication(String username, String password) {
        Users user = null;
        user = GetUser(username);
        if (user == null) {
            return "notExist";
        }
        String salt = user.getSalt();
        byte[] hashed = HashSha256(password.concat(salt));
        String encryptedPassword = bytesToString(hashed);

        System.out.println("haslo:" + password + ", salt:" + salt + ", sha: " + encryptedPassword + " == " + user.getPassword());
//Until next line everything works properly.
        return encryptedPassword.equals(user.getPassword()) == true ? "true" : "false";
    }
```

Methods Hash256 and byteToString works properly
And My front

komponentyZlozone:Logowanie is a CompositeComponent

```
        <center>
            <h:form class="centered Form">
                <h3 style="font-size: 50px">Oto Nasz Dom</h3>

                <komponentyZlozone:Logowanie 
                    usernameLabel="#{bundle['logowanie.pseudonim']}"
                    usernameValue="#{loginController.user}"
                    passwordLabel="#{bundle['logowanie.haslo']}"
                    passwordValue="#{loginController.pwd}"

                    loginButtonLabel="#{bundle['logowanie.zaloguj']}"
                    loginButtonAction="#{loginController.validateUsernamePassword()}" 

                    />

                <br/><br/>
                <h:button value="Rejestracja" outcome="userRegister" style="font-size: 25px; box-shadow: gray; padding: 5px;">
                    <f:ajax  execute="toogle" render="toogleRender" event="click"/>
                </h:button>
            </h:form>
        </center>
```

CompositeComponent "Blueprint"

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:composite = "http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name = "usernameLabel" />
        <composite:attribute name = "usernameValue" />
        <composite:attribute name = "passwordLabel" />
        <composite:attribute name = "passwordValue" />

        <composite:attribute name = "loginButtonLabel" />
        <composite:attribute name = "loginButtonAction" 
                             method-signature = "java.lang.String validateUsernamePassword()" />
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns = "2" id = "loginPanel">
                #{cc.attrs.usernameLabel} : 
                <h:inputText id = "username" value = "#{cc.attrs.usernameValue}"    required="true" />
                #{cc.attrs.passwordLabel} : 
                <h:inputSecret id = "password" value = "#{cc.attrs.passwordValue}"  required="true" />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton 
                action = "#{cc.attrs.loginButtonAction}" 
                value = "#{cc.attrs.loginButtonLabel}"
                style="padding: 10px"
                />
        </h:form>
    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

Thanks for help!

edit.
I don't uderstand why i'm getting this error. During debugging i could not find out what's the problem. :(

Comment: The error message tells you that a constraint was violated, quote: Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'preUpdate'. Please refer to embedded ConstraintViolations for details.

Comment: Read the **FULL** stacktrace, read [ask], read [mcve]...

Comment: I found out the exact answer, here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070684/8950911